# Reload all open files in emacs after git branch change

Tags: git, emacs, editor, magit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Emacs to revert all unchanged buffers when switching branches in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665600/how-can-i-get-emacs-to-revert-all-unchanged-buffers-when-switching-branches-in-gi)

I have more than 15 files of the same project open in emacs. When i change the branch in git i have to manually reload all files again. Is there an option to reload files automatically in magit?

Comment: This might do the trick for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480572/how-to-have-emacs-auto-refresh-all-buffers-when-files-have-changed-on-disk